# Activator.CreateInstance - Not able to use the return type

Tags: c#, object, ioc-container

I am trying to hand-roll my own [IoC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) tool.

This is a part of IoC code:

```
public static object Resolve(Type contract)
{
   Type Implementation = typeSettings[contract];

   ConstructorInfo constructor = Implementation.GetConstructors()[0];

   ParameterInfo[] constructorParam = constructor.GetParameters();

   if (constructorParam.Length == 0)
      Activator.CreateInstance(Implementation);

   List<object> paramList = new List<object>(constructorParam.Length);

   foreach(ParameterInfo param in constructorParam)
      paramList.Add(Resolve(param.ParameterType));

   return constructor.Invoke(paramList.ToArray());
}
```

I want to return an object of the generic type T. I am not able to do that.

I am not able to typecast it either. I am using only one interface with two dependencies.
(`IPredictingFuture`, `EartAndSkyPrediction`, `BadConnections`)

I am trying to typecast it to the Interface type. (In order to access the methods in my client code.) But that is not working out either.

What am I missing?

Comment: "I am not able to typecast it either." - why not? It's really not clear what you're trying to do, or why you'd *expect* to be able to use members of a type which you only know at execution time...

Comment: @JonSkeet, Let me add more code to clear it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, for the response.
I added this overridden Resolve method

```
public static T Resolve<T>() { return (T)Resolve(typeof(T)); }
```

Now, I get the type properly. This is the client code:

```
IPredictingFuture predictions;
predictions = IoC.Resolve<IPredictingFuture>();
```

This way, the intellisense after predictions works just fine.

If any of the readers landed up at this question because they are trying to cook up an IoC container, I would point them to these great links:

1. [33 liner IoC by Ken](http://kenegozi.com/Blog/2008/01/17/its-my-turn-to-build-an-ioc-container-in-15-minutes-and-33-lines)
2. [15 liner IoC by Ayende](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2007/10/20/Building-an-IoC-container-in-15-lines-of-code.aspx)
3. Followup [post by Ayende](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2007/10/20/Dependency-Injection-doesnt-cut-it-anymore.aspx) on why you should not be coding your own IoC
4. [Good link](http://blog.agafonov.net.ua/post/2010/09/17/Inversion-of-control-%28IOC%29-NET-patterns.aspx) about IoC containers
5. [Another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386535/code-your-own-ioc-container) which talks about IoC

Answer (score 1):

In your method, `contract` is only known at runtime, so it cannot be used at compile time. Depending on your callers, you may be able to change it to a generic type parameter, in which case you can do:

```
public static object Resolve(Type contract)
{
   Type Implementation = typeSettings[contract];

   ConstructorInfo constructor = Implementation.GetConstructors()[0];

   ParameterInfo[] constructorParam = constructor.GetParameters();

   if (constructorParam.Length == 0)
      Activator.CreateInstance(Implementation);

   List<object> paramList = new List<object>(constructorParam.Length);

   foreach(ParameterInfo param in constructorParam)
      paramList.Add(Resolve(param.ParameterType));

   return constructor.Invoke(paramList.ToArray());
}

public static T Resolve<T>()
{
   return (T)Resolve(typeof(T));
}
```

Overloaded because as you mention, `Resolve(Type)` calls itself recursively, and the generic version cannot call itself like that.

Comment: I don't think this would work. The actual code uses recursion. It calls resolve again. `paramList.Add(Resolve(param.ParameterType));
`. I am trying to overload Resolve now...

Comment: @TheSilverBullet Ah, I missed that. Yes, overloading would solve that, I'll edit.

Comment: @TheSilverBullet Edited, this way you can either call `Resolve<IPredictingFuture>()`, which is known at compile-time to return `IPredictingFuture`, or you can call `Resolve(typeof(IPredictingFuture))`, which returns an `object` which you'd have to cast at the caller's side.

Comment: @TheSilverBullet And I hadn't noticed you already put this in your own answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Adjusting the namespace for this venue, I've used this for years...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using DataAccess.Core.DataInterfaces;
using DataAccess.Core.Utils;

namespace StackOverflowExample
{
    public class SimpleIoC<T>
    {
        public T getInstance()
        {
            return getInstance(null);
        }

        public T getInstance(object[] initializationParameters)
        {
            Type type = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), initializationParameters).GetType();
            // Any special initialization for an object should be placed in a case statement
            // using that object's type name
            switch (type.ToString())
            {
                // Example
                //case "DataAccess.Data.ApplicantDao":
                //    // - Do pre-instanciation initialization stuff here -
                //    return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), initializationParameters);
                default:
                    return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), initializationParameters);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure if this one will help you, but I use this as part of a Business Rule Evaluation Engine...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading;

namespace StackOverflowExample
{
    public static class DynamicObjectFactory
    {
        private static readonly object _lock = new object();

        public static object getInstance(string assemblyName, string className)
        {
            Monitor.Enter(_lock);
            try
            {
                System.Reflection.Assembly asm = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(assemblyName);
                return asm.CreateInstance(className, false, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.CreateInstance, null, null, null, null);
            }
            finally
            {
                Monitor.Exit(_lock);
            }
        }

    public static object getInstance(string assemblyName, string className, object[] constructorParameters)
    {
        Monitor.Enter(_lock);
        try
        {
            System.Reflection.Assembly asm = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(assemblyName);
            return asm.CreateInstance(className, false, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.CreateInstance, null, constructorParameters, null, null);
        }
        finally
        {
            Monitor.Exit(_lock);
        }
    }
}
```

}