# Simple Dependency Resolver

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection

How do you create simple Dependency Resolver, with out using any built in or library such as Autofac, Ninject, etc.

This was my interview question.

I wrote this simple code and they said it does not look good. Its like very hard coded idea.

```
public interface IRepository { }
interface IDataProvider
{
    List<string> GetData();
}
public class SQLDataProvider : IDataProvider
{
    private readonly IRepository _repository { get; set; }
    public SQLDataProvider(IRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }
    public List<string> GetData()
    {
        return new List<string> { "" };
    }
}
public class MockDataProvider : IDataProvider
{
    public List<string> GetData()
    {
        return new List<string> { "" };
    }
}
class Program
{
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
    string targetClass = "SQLDataProvider";
    //Here i need to supply IRepository instance too 
   IDataProvider dataProvider = 
   (IDataProvider)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(IDataProvider), targetClass);

  }
}
```

What better code i do and supply other object instance for constructor parameter?

Comment: Most of the IoC containers are open source, e.g. [SimpleInjector](http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/) and [Autofac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/source/browse/), so you can peek for inspiration. Word of warning - the implementation is *not* trivial.

Comment: on a side note, that's an incredibly retarded interview question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it's basically asking for a code review. It belongs on "Code Review" instead.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/386535/code-your-own-ioc-container/1721589?noredirect=1#comment33256865_1721589

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking to critique code

Answer (score 49):

[DI Containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50718586/what-is-a-di-container/50724263#50724263) are complex libraries. Building them takes years and maintaining them decades. But to demonstrate their working, you can write a simplistic implementations in just a few lines of code.

At its core a DI Container would typically wrap a dictionary with `System.Type` as its key and, the value would be some object that allows you to create new instances of that type. When you write a simplistic implementation `System.Func<object>` would do. Here is an example that contains several `Register` methods, both a generic and non-generic `GetInstance` method and allows [Auto-Wiring](https://livebook.manning.com/book/dependency-injection-principles-practices-patterns/chapter-12/44):

```cs
public class Container
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, Func<object>> regs = new();

    public void Register<TService, TImpl>() where TImpl : TService =>
        regs.Add(typeof(TService), () => this.GetInstance(typeof(TImpl)));

    public void Register<TService>(Func<TService> factory) =>
        regs.Add(typeof(TService), () => factory());

    public void RegisterInstance<TService>(TService instance) =>
        regs.Add(typeof(TService), () => instance);

    public void RegisterSingleton<TService>(Func<TService> factory)
    {
        var lazy = new Lazy<TService>(factory);
        Register(() => lazy.Value);
    }

    public object GetInstance(Type type)
    {
        if (regs.TryGetValue(type, out Func<object> fac)) return fac();
        else if (!type.IsAbstract) return this.CreateInstance(type);
        throw new InvalidOperationException("No registration for " + type);
    }

    private object CreateInstance(Type implementationType)
    {
        var ctor = implementationType.GetConstructors().Single();
        var paramTypes = ctor.GetParameters().Select(p => p.ParameterType);
        var dependencies = paramTypes.Select(GetInstance).ToArray();
        return Activator.CreateInstance(implementationType, dependencies);
    }
}
```

You can use it as follows:

```cs
var container = new Container();

container.RegisterInstance<ILogger>(new FileLogger("c:\\logs\\log.txt"));

// SqlUserRepository depends on ILogger
container.Register<IUserRepository, SqlUserRepository>();

// HomeController depends on IUserRepository
// Concrete instances don't need to be resolved
container.GetInstance(typeof(HomeController));
```

> **WARNING: You should *never* use such naive and simplistic implementation as given above. It lacks many important features that mature DI libraries give you, yet gives no advantage over using [Pure DI](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/) (i.e. hand wiring object graphs). You lose compile-time support, without getting anything back.**

When your application is small, you should start with Pure DI and once your application and your DI configuration grow to the point that maintaining you [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/) becomes cumbersome, you could consider switching to one of the established DI libraries.

Here are some of the features that this naive implementation lacks compared to the established libraries:

- **Auto-Registration:** The ability to apply Convention over Configuration by registering a set of types with in single line, instead of having to register each type manually.
- **Interception:** the ability to apply decorators or interceptors for a range of types
- **Generics:** Mapping open-generic abstractions to open generic implementations
- **Integration:** using the library with common application platforms (such as ASP.NET MVC, Web API, .NET Core, etc)
- **Lifetime Management:** The ability to registering types with custom lifestyles (e.g. Scoped or Per Request).
- **Error handling:** Detection of misconfiguration such as cyclic dependencies. This simplistic implementation throws a stack overflow exception.
- **Verification:** Features or tools for verifying the correctness of the configuration (to compensate the loss of compile-time support) and diagnosing common configuration mistakes.
- **Performance:** Building large object graphs will be slow using this simplistic implementation (e.g. causes a lot of GC pressure due to the amount of produced garbage).

These features and abilities allow you to keep your DI configuration maintainable when using a DI Container.

Comment: Here container.GetInstance(typeof(HomeController))  returns Object type, Is it possible to  TypeCast and return the HomeController type from GetInstance() method itself, i tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36750123/creating-custom-container-class-in-c-sharp?noredirect=1#comment61083046_36750123 in this code, but getting some sytax error

Comment: Dear Steven, how would you modify your code to create a method that has the standard service locator signature..i.e. var instance = _container.GetInstance<IDoSomeStuff>()?

Comment: You don't. You either use Pure DI or use a common DI library.

Comment: @Steven can you elaborate on why you can't?

Comment: The warning in my answer explains this.

Answer (score 7):

It's already a few years old, but Ayende once wrote a blog post about this:
[Building an IoC container in 15 lines of code](http://ayende.com/blog/2886/building-an-ioc-container-in-15-lines-of-code)

But this is only the very simplest possible implementation.
Ayende himself stated in his [next post](http://ayende.com/blog/2887/dependency-injection-doesnt-cut-it-anymore) that the existing IoC containers can do much more stuff than just returning class instances - and this is where it gets complicated.
As "Trust me - I'm a Doctor" already said in his comment: implementing a *complete* IoC container is everything but trivial.