# Constructor Dependency injection in asp.net core 2

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-2.0

I have read this official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection.

There is something i do not understand in constructor injection:

Let's have a look to my code, which works fine:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<Utilisateurs> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<Utilisateurs> _signInManager;
    private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;

    public HomeController(
        SignInManager<Utilisateurs> signInManager,
        UserManager<Utilisateurs> userManager,
        RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _roleManager = roleManager;
    }
```

It works fine too if change constructor parameter orders or if i remove some parameters like this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<Utilisateurs> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<Utilisateurs> _signInManager;

    public HomeController(
        UserManager<Utilisateurs> userManager
        SignInManager<Utilisateurs> signInManager,
        )
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
    }
```

I have understood the concept of DI. What i do not understand is how does it works in C# to have something dynamic in constructor parameters ?
Is there a set of all kind of overload constructors ?

Thanks

Comment: You need to clarify your question. What do you mean by `have something dynamic in constructor parameters`? Are you referring to the `dynamic` key word?

Comment: Might help to look at what a really simple [hand-rolled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15715978/simple-dependency-resolver#15717047) DI implementation actually does - nothing particularly clever is required. Obviously fully-fledged DI frameworks are more evolved, but at their core, they are just doing the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how does it work in C# to have something dynamic in constructor parameters ? Is there a set of all kind of overload constructors?

Don't use "dynamic" like that, it's a buzzword in that sentence. In programming, everything is dynamic.

If you mean to ask how a DI framework can match up registered services with constructor parameters, then yes, there is a set of constructor overloads.

The DI framework finds these through reflection, see [MSDN: `Type.GetConstructors()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e687hf0d(v=vs.110).aspx). Then for each constructor, the framework [obtains the parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getparameters(v=vs.110).aspx) of each constructor, matches those up with the registered services and invokes one of the constructors.