# How exactly does Dependency Injection work in .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

Well, most of the web applications developed in Visual Studio use DI for all the modular functionalities and most of the developers know how to implement it too. But I would like to know the exact internal mechanism by which DI injects or creates instances of the desired classes in side constructors. The injected classes may have their own constructor injection, and thus chaining down several classes with their own DI. can anyone shed some light on this. Knowing this may help one to tweak and customize DI requirements. Thanks

Comment: If you really want to see the internals [you can check the source code itself](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/tree/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection). .NET Core is open source and all files are available on GitHub. I suspect you have a specific question in mind though. There are no `side constructors` so I suspect the real question is how does DI decide which constructor to use? That's described in the [Multiple Constructor Discovery Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection#multiple-constructor-discovery-rules)  docs

Comment: This question is by far too broad. Explaining the internals of some framework in a single answer is like "please explain how digestion works in a human body". There are so many things to cover, questions to be asked. We don't even have any idea how far into detail you want to go.

Comment: Conceptually it is fairly simple. Use reflection to list constructors and figure out dependencies, repeat the same for the dependencies until you you find types that already have an instance, or can be trivially created. then create all the instances on the way back up the recursion tree. I would expect reality to be much more complicated however.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15715978/simple-dependency-resolver/15717047#15717047) shows a minimalistic DI Container implementation that demonstrates how DI Containers work behind the covers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET Core and its libraries are open source and hosted on GitHub. If you really want to see the internals [you can check the source code itself](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/tree/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection).

I suspect the real question is how does DI decide which constructor to use? That's described in the [Multiple Constructor Discovery Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection#multiple-constructor-discovery-rules)  section of the DI docs :

> The constructor with the most parameters where the types are DI-resolvable is selected.

and

> If there's ambiguity when discovering constructors, an exception is thrown.

The section give an example. In the following example only `ILogger<ExampleService>` is registered. Should a class request an `ExampleService` instance, the `ExampleService(ILogger<ExampleService> logger)`  will be used:

```
public class ExampleService
{
    public ExampleService()
    {
    }

    public ExampleService(ILogger<ExampleService> logger)
    {
        // omitted for brevity
    }

    public ExampleService(FooService fooService, BarService barService)
    {
        // omitted for brevity
    }
}
```

On the other hand, the following class will cause an exception if both ILogger<> and IOptions<> are registered :

```
public class ExampleService
{
    public ExampleService()
    {
    }

    public ExampleService(ILogger<ExampleService> logger)
    {
        // omitted for brevity
    }

    public ExampleService(IOptions<ExampleOptions> options)
    {
        // omitted for brevity
    }
}
```

To solve this the docs propose adding a constructor with both dependencies

```
public ExampleService(
    ILogger<ExampleService> logger,
    IOptions<ExampleOptions> options)
{
    // omitted for brevity
}
```